# Filter nested python dict by value

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary, where I don't exactly know, how deeply nested it is, but here is an example of such:

```
{
   "name":"a_struct",
   "type":"int",
   "data":{
      "type":"struct",
      "elements":[
         {
            "data":[
               {
                  "name":"test1",
                  "data_id":0,
                  "type":"uint8",
                  "wire_type":0,
                  "data":0
               },
               {
                  "name":"test2",
                  "data_id":2,
                  "type":"uint32",
                  "wire_type":2,
                  "data":0
               },
               {
                  "name":"test3",
                  "data_id":3,
                  "type":"int",
                  "wire_type":4,
                  "data":{
                     "type":"uint32",
                     "elements":[
                        
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "name":"test4",
                  "data_id":4,
                  "type":"uint32",
                  "wire_type":2,
                  "data":0
               },
               {
                  "name":"test5",
                  "data_id":5,
                  "type":"int",
                  "wire_type":4,
                  "data":{
                     "type":"uint32",
                     "elements":[
                        
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My goal is to filter out each dictionary that does not contains values **["test1", "test3", "test5"]** by the **name** key. **This shall be applicable to various deeply nested dictionaries.**

So in that case, the result shall be **a filtered dictionary**:

```
{
   "name":"a_struct",
   "type":"int",
   "data":{
      "type":"struct",
      "elements":[
         {
            "data":[
               {
                  "name":"test1",
                  "data_id":0,
                  "type":"uint8",
                  "wire_type":0,
                  "data":0
               },
               {
                  "name":"test3",
                  "data_id":3,
                  "type":"int",
                  "wire_type":4,
                  "data":{
                     "type":"uint32",
                     "elements":[
                        
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "name":"test5",
                  "data_id":5,
                  "type":"int",
                  "wire_type":4,
                  "data":{
                     "type":"uint32",
                     "elements":[
                        
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried to use the dpath lib (https://pypi.org/project/dpath/), by providing a filter criteria like so:

```
def afilter(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        if "name" in x:
            if x["name"] in ["test1", "test3", "test5"]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    else:
        return False

result = dpath.util.search(my_dict, "**", afilter=afilter)
```

But I get a wrong result, so every other key, has been filtered out, which is not what I want:

```
{
   "data":{
      "elements":[
         {
            "data":[
               {
                  "name":"test1",
                  "data_id":0,
                  "type":"uint8",
                  "wire_type":0,
                  "data":0
               },
               null,
               {
                  "name":"test3",
                  "data_id":3,
                  "type":"int",
                  "wire_type":4,
                  "data":{
                     "type":"uint32",
                     "elements":[
                        
                     ]
                  }
               },
               null,
               {
                  "name":"test5",
                  "data_id":5,
                  "type":"int",
                  "wire_type":4,
                  "data":{
                     "type":"uint32",
                     "elements":[
                        
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How to get this right?

PS: I'm not forced to use the dpath lib. So, the solution might be written in pure python.

Comment: `element = my_dict['data']['elements'][0]` and `element['data'] = [d for d in element['data'] if d['name'] not in ('test1', 'test3', 'test5')]`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a more generic and flexible solution. Therefore, I edited my question.

Comment: Interestingly, I looked into `dpath`, and even their own example under [Filtering](https://github.com/dpath-maintainers/dpath-python#filtering) does not work correctly. It seems to just print the input program.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively process your dictionary while filtering unneeded records:

```
def delete_keys(data, keys_to_keep):
    res = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            res[k] = delete_keys(v, keys_to_keep)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            if k == "data":
                res[k] = [delete_keys(obj, keys_to_keep) for obj in v if obj.get('name') in keys_to_keep]
            else:
                res[k] = [delete_keys(obj, keys_to_keep) for obj in v]
        else:
            res[k] = v
    return res

keys_to_keep = {'test1', 'test3', 'test5'}
print(delete_keys(data, keys_to_keep))
```

For your input, it gives:

```
{
    "name": "a_struct",
    "type": "int",
    "data": {
        "type": "struct",
        "elements": [
            {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "test1",
                        "data_id": 0,
                        "type": "uint8",
                        "wire_type": 0,
                        "data": 0,
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "test3",
                        "data_id": 3,
                        "type": "int",
                        "wire_type": 4,
                        "data": {"type": "uint32", "elements": []},
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "test5",
                        "data_id": 5,
                        "type": "int",
                        "wire_type": 4,
                        "data": {"type": "uint32", "elements": []},
                    },
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
}
```